# Total row count for vaadin table

Tags: java, vaadin, rowcount

Is there a method to get the total number of rows for vaadin table?

Does `getrowcount()` method works for vaadin table also?

Can any one help?

Comment: Can you show code you have tried related to this question?

Comment: my vaadin table name is namesTable so tried using namesTable.getrowcount whuch usually works but here in vaadin I dont know why it is not working. Is there any other method for getting row counts particular to vaadin table?

Comment: Usuallay you have a container as datasource, and there exists a size() method which returns the number of "unfiltered" items. [link]https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.html#size%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table` has the `size()` method that returns the total number of visible rows. If you don't have any `Filter`s applied to the `Table` (or underlying `Container`) that will return the total number of rows.